# SQL Query performance - UI responsiveness concerns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query on localhost, I am extremely unfamiliar with SQL. I am using a golang library to generate the query statement. This is for an enterprise app so I don't have time to evaluate and code all possible performance cases. I'd prefer good performance for the largest possible queries:

- upto 6 query parameters eg. BETWEEN 'created' AND 'abandoned', BETWEEN X AND Y, IN (1,2,3.....25), IN ('A', 'B', 'C'....'Z')
- JOINs/subqueries between a 2-5 tables
- returning between 50K-5M records (LAT and LNG)

Currently I am using JOIN to find the lat, lng for a record, and some query parameters. Should I join differently, (left, right)? Should the FROM table be the record or the relation? Subqueries?

Is this query performance reasonable from a UI perspective? This is on localhost (docker) on a fairly low performance laptop, under WSL (16GB RAM / 6 core CPU [2.2GHz]).

```sql
-- [2547.438ms] [rows:874731] 
SELECT  "Longitude","Latitude" 
FROM    Wells
JOIN    Well_Reports ON Well_Reports.Well_ID       = Wells.Well_ID 
JOIN    Lithologies  on Lithologies.Well_Report_ID = Well_Reports.Well_Report_ID 
where   Lithologies.Colour IN 
        (
           'NULL',
           'Gray','White','Dark','Black','Dark Gray','Dark Brown','Dark Red','Dark Blue',
           'Dark Green','Dark Yellow','Bluish Green','Brownish Gray','Brownish Green','Brownish Yellow',
           'Light','Light Gray','Light Red','Greenish Gray','Light Yellow','Light Green','Light Blue',
           'Light Brown','Blue Gray','Greenish Yellow','Greenish Gray'
        );
```

- The UI is a heatmap. I haven't really hit performance issues returning 1-million rows.
- Angular is the framework. Im breaking the HTTP response into 10K record chunks

My initial impression was 3+ seconds is too long for a UI to start populating data. I was already breaking the response to the UI into chunks, that portion was efficient and async. It never occurred to me to simply break the SQL requests into smaller chunks with LIMIT and OFFSET, so the server can start responding with data immediately (<200ms) even if it takes +5s to completely finish loading.

I'll write an answer to this effect.

Thanks and best regards,
schmorrison

Comment: You need to be more specific; what is "reasonable" performance? If you've not had any issues, then what is your question? Because if it's is SQL good at querying data, then the answer is yes. If you need it to be quicker, limit your results or do a deep dive

Comment: If you want good performance for dynamic queries that return 5 million rows, then you'll need to learn the intricacies of database engines, not only SQL. A high level knowledge unfortunately won't cut it.

Comment: `returning between 50K-5M records` *don't* return 50K rows. Not even 500 rows. You can't display 500 rows in any grid unless the screen is as tall as a house. Load and display only what can be displayed. That's what *all* applications and web sites do. Many use paging, some use infinite or virtual scrolling to give the impression of loading all rows when they actually only load the next page. Most UI stacks support virtual scrolling in one form or another, loading the next 3-5 rows to give the impression of smooth scrolling.

Comment: This question is only 1% about SQL, and 110% about your UI stack. What *is* your UI stack? WPF? Windows Forms? MVC? Razor Pages? Blazor? All of them have paging and virtual scrolling in one form or another

Comment: Sorry, I'm adding to my question the following:
- The UI is a heatmap. I haven't really hit performance issues returning 1-million rows.
- Angular is the framework. Im breaking the HTTP response into 10K record chunks. 
- sorry, the NULL is a string. I just forgot the quotes when I was copying.

I do also appreciate the comment by The Impaler, I won't spend too much time getting it right perfect right now :)

Comment: SQL Server has `geometry` and `geography` types and indexes. If you want to create a GIS application with good performance you'll have to use these.

Comment: `right now` so use paging. It's as simple as that. Even better, use `GROUP BY` to calculate the statistics you want to display in the heatmap instead of trying to calculate them on the far weaker, single-threaded client from 5M rows.  It's easier to calculate a heatmap (or anything else for that matter) by reading data little by little and processing it. Otherwise your application will just freeze waiting for all 5M rows to load before it even starts to process the data

Comment: These are public datasets from institutional providers, several DBs with different table schemes. I'd rather not have to preprocess their data just for structuring.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on paging. I'll look into how to implement that in this particular situation.

Comment: Don't run the query and the image processing on the UI thread. Asynchronously query and process the data in chunks. Hand those chunks back to the UI as a kind of batched stream (concurrent queue / producer consumer) if you want it to render in patches over time rather than all at once. This question seems more like a golang question than a SQL question.

Comment: 5M rows may be a lot for a client but very little data for a database. Preprocessing is very easy and can improve performance immensely. Calculating distances, finding the nearest neighbor or overlapping complex geometries (or even wells inside a specific field) is a lot faster using spatial indexes

Comment: So what I guess I don't understand is if I preprocess the data, I am still retrieving all the rows from the DB on every query and performing operations on it. Or can I add something to the statement to perform calculations on the SQL server?

The client requests are async and the server responds in chunks. I am also caching because the responses do not change over time.

Comment: Aight, thanks everyone. I get it. I can limit the number of records the SQL query can return per statement, and execute the statements concurrently, then write the data back to the client as the SQL queries return.

Should I write an answer for this myself?

Comment: Sounds like you have a plan, one comment though... you mentioned "calculations" on the SQL server. If the calculations are just about picking the right set of points - ie, the filtering of the data, then yeah you definitely want to use spatial types. However, if you mean something other than this, you probably want some other machine to do those calculations. SQL Server CPU time is a lot more expensive than non SQL Server CPU time because of licensing. Let SQL do what it's good at (fetching the data), and hand that off for further processing.

Comment: So some of the DBs have coordinates as UTM (easting, northing) INT which I am converting to lat,lng others have lat, lng as REAL, still others have lat, lng as STRING. Do the GIS index types work on arbitrary data types?

Comment: No, only on spatial types. If you are stuck with the database schemas as they are then unfortunately there's not much you can do on that front. If you can get the databases to ingest the data spatially in the first place, or get an indexed computed column added, that might be a plus. Persisted computed geospatial columns have been possible since SQL 2012, although I have never actually tried indexing a computed geospatial column, so I can't comment on that possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by The Impaler,

> "If you want good performance for dynamic queries that return 5
> million rows, then you'll need to learn the intricacies of database
> engines, not only SQL. A high level knowledge unfortunately won't cut
> it."

and I expected as much.

I was simply querying the SQL DB for the whole set at once, this is ***wrong*** and I know that.

The changes I made generates the following statements (I know the specifics have changed):

```sql
-- [145.955ms] [rows:1]
SELECT     count(*) 
FROM       "tblWellLogs" 
WHERE      (
             DateWellCompleted BETWEEN 
             '1800-01-01 06:58:00.000' AND '2021-09-12 06:00:00.000'
           ) 
AND        "FinalStatusOfWellL" NOT IN 
           (
             5,6,7,8,9,16,27,36
           ) 
AND        WaterUseL IN 
           (
             1,29,3,8,26,4,6
           ) 
AND        (
             wyRate BETWEEN
             0 AND 3321
           ) 
AND        (
             TotalOrFinishedDepth BETWEEN
             0 AND 248
           );
```

```
Calculated total(69977)  chunk (17494)   currentpage(3)
```

```sql
-- [117.195ms] [rows:17494]
SELECT     "Easting","Northing" 
FROM       "tblWellLogs" 
WHERE      (
             DateWellCompleted BETWEEN 
             '1800-01-01 06:58:00.000' AND '2021-09-12 06:00:00.000'
           ) 
AND        "FinalStatusOfWellL" NOT IN 
           (
             5,6,7,8,9,16,27,36
           ) 
AND        WaterUseL IN 
           (
             1,29,3,8,26,4,6
           ) 
AND        (
             wyRate BETWEEN
             0 AND 3321
           ) 
AND        (
             TotalOrFinishedDepth BETWEEN 
             0 AND 248
           )
ORDER BY   (SELECT NULL)
OFFSET     34988 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 17494 ROWS ONLY;
```

```
Chunk count: 17494
JSON size: 385135
Request time: 278.6612ms
```

The response to the UI is as so:

```
GET /data/wells/xxxx/?page=3&completed.start=1800-01-01T06:58:36.000Z&completed.end=2021-09-12T06:00:00.000Z&status=supply,research,geothermal,other,unknown&use=domestic,commercial,industrial,municipal,irrigation,agriculture&depth.start=0&depth.end=248&rate.start=0&rate.end=3321&page=3 HTTP/1.1 200 385135
```

```json
{
  "data":[[0.0, 0.0],......],
  "count": 87473,
  "total": 874731,
  "pages": 11,
  "page": 1
}
```

In this case, the DBs are essentially immutable (I may get an updated dataset once per year). I figure I can predefine a set of chunk size variations for each DB based on query result size rather than just DB size. I am also retrieving the next page before the client requests it. I am caching requests at the browser and client layers. I only perform the `Count(*)` request if the client doesn't provide it, and it isn't in the cache.

I did find that running the request concurrently simply over-burdened my CPU, all the requests returned almost simultaneously but took +5s each rather than ~1second each.

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

```
where someColumn in (null, ...)
```

This will not return rows where the value of `someColumn` is `null` because, `x in (a, b, c ...)` translates to `x = a or x = b or x = c`, and `null` is not equal to `null`.

You need a construct like this instead

```
where someColumn is null or someColumn in (...)
```

Second, you mentioned you're returning between 50k and 5M rows to the UI. I question the sanity of this... how is the UI rendering 5 million sets of coordinates for the user to see/use? I suppose there could be some extreme edge cases where this is really what you need to do, but it just seems really unlikely.

Third, if your concern is UI responsiveness, the proper way to handle that is to make asynchronous requests. I don't know anything about golang, but I did find [this page](https://hackernoon.com/asyncawait-in-golang-an-introductory-guide-ol1e34sg) with a quick google search. Study up on that kind of technique.

Finally, if you really do need to work with data sets this big, the critical point will be to identify the common search criteria and talk to your DBA about appropriate indexes. We can't provide much help in this regard without a lot more schema information, but if you have a specific query that is taking a long time with a particular set of parameters, you can come back and create a question for that query, along with providing the query plan, and we can help you out.

Comment: `to make asynchronous requests.` not at all. It doesn't matter how you load 5K rows (much less 50K or 5M). trying to display all of them in a grid will freeze the UI thread and waste a lot of memory. Applications use *paging* to avoid this, to load eg only 50 rows at a time. A single page may be loaded using async operations or not

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "Second, you mentioned you're returning between 50k and 5M rows to the UI. I question the sanity of this... " The question of the size of the data set being returned is independent of the question of UI responsiveness.

Comment: It doesn't *make* the third part correct. The third part is simply correct in its own right: `waitfor delay '00:00:30; select * from t order by c offset 10 rows fetch next 10 rows only;`. I say again, the size of the dataset being returned and any techinques you use to page that is independent of the question of UI responsiveness.